# R: Keep rows if a term from a separate vector appears in the row

Tags: r

I have a vector of terms:

```
terms <- c("white blood cell", "acp5 mutation", "acquired immunodeficiency syndrome", 
"activated pi3k delta syndrome", "acute disseminated encephalomyelitis"
)

> terms
[1] "white blood cell"                    
[2] "acp5 mutation"                       
[3] "acquired immunodeficiency syndrome"  
[4] "activated pi3k delta syndrome"       
[5] "acute disseminated encephalomyelitis"
```

And a dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(22952603L, 20639394L, 27989323L, 
29221444L, 30595370L, 30595370L), TRAIT = c("acp5 mutation syndrome", 
"Bilirubin levels", "Macrophage colony stimulating factor levels", 
"Coronary artery calcified atherosclerotic plaque score in type 2 diabetes", 
"White blood cell count", "Red cell distribution width")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

> df
# A tibble: 6 x 2
        ID TRAIT                                                                
     <int> <chr>                                                                
1 22952603 acp5 mutation syndrome                                               
2 20639394 Bilirubin levels                                                     
3 27989323 Macrophage colony stimulating factor levels                          
4 29221444 Coronary artery calcified atherosclerotic plaque score in type 2 dia…
5 30595370 White blood cell count                                               
6 30595370 Red cell distribution width
```

I want to be able to run through each row of my data frame, and if a term from the `terms` vector appears within the `TRAIT` column for that row, I want to keep that row.

eg. the resulting data frame would look like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
        ID TRAIT                                                                
     <int> <chr>                                                                
1 22952603 acp5 mutation syndrome                                               
2 30595370 White blood cell count
```

Since both "acp5 mutation" and "white blood cell" appear within the terms list.

What is the best way to go about creating this dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
subset(df, grepl(paste(terms, collapse = '|'), tolower(TRAIT)))

#         ID                  TRAIT
# 1 22952603 acp5 mutation syndrome
# 5 30595370 White blood cell count
```

Similarly but using `[` instead of subset:

```
df[grep(paste(terms, collapse = '|'), tolower(df$TRAIT)), ]
```

Answer (score -1):

So your terms don't perfectly align, but assuming they do in your actual dataset, you could just to:

```
df%>%
    mutate(new = ifelse(terms %in% TRAIT, 1, NA))
```

and then just filter out the NAs.

Comment: Why would you downvote this?--does exactly what OP asked

Comment: Your answer does not mention which libraries you've used, and it does not answer OPs question at all since it produces errors with the example provided.

Comment: Mutate is a pretty standard function--quite sure that someone with 149 points on SO would know that it's in the dplyr/tidyverse library. Not sure why/how you got errors...I wouldn't have posted it if I got errors.

Comment: The terms do not align in the example, why would you assume that the full scope of the code is simpler than the example? Did you edit the provided data so that your code would work?

Comment: Nope. Just cut and pasted. I'd assume that because the terms are near identical, and in my experience, when terms are that close, there's usually an error or oversight involved. Moreover, the OP provides a vector of five observations...that vector could easily be changed. If it were an entire dataset, it would be a different matter. It's great that you appreciate BaseR, but many people like the ease of Dplyr. Additionally, SO isn't a coding service...easy tweaks aren't a huge burden on the OP. I just would never downvote someone for giving their time on this forum.

Comment: The downvote is specifically because `terms %in% TRAIT` returns all false since there are no exact matches. The difference between code that accounts for the "near identical" nature is not an "easy tweak" away.

Comment: I would define cutting and pasting as an "easy tweak"--the vector was obviously created from somewhere. Regardless, given the current state of things in our country, this is too stupid to continue. You do what you want.

Comment: Do you really think that OP is going to search the entire phrase `Coronary artery calcified atherosclerotic plaque score in type 2 dia…`, No they'll want to search something like `Coronary artery`.By "our country" you mean USA? I am not from that country. Maybe leave the world politics out of a coding discussion.